# Implement QThread with QProgressBar in PySide (or PyQt) during calculation

Tags: python, qthread, pyside2, qprogressbar

I would like to know how to implement QProgressBar, which shows the progress of calculation in main thread.

Please refer to below codes.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread

class BarThread(QThread):

    # Progress Bar UI Definition
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.window = QWidget()
        self.pgsb = QProgressBar()
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.pgsb)
        self.window.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.isRun = False

    # Thread Function Definition
    def run(self):
        self.window.show()
        while self.isRun:
            self.pgsb.setValue(self.percent)
            print(self.percent)
            if self.percent == 100:
                self.isRun = False


class Tool(QWidget):

    # Main UI Definition
    def __init__(self):
        windowWidth = 300
        windowHeight = 300
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")
        self.resize(windowWidth, windowHeight)
        self.bt = QPushButton('Numbering')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.bt)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    # Main Function Link Definition
        self.bt.clicked.connect(self.numbering)

    # Main Function Definition
    def numbering(self):
        bth = BarThread()
        bth.start()
        bth.isRun = True
        for x in range(0,100000):
            bth.percent = x/1000
            print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Tool()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can copy and paste directly onto your python IDE.

(it needs PySide2. It can be installed with 'pip install pyside2' in your prompt).

This code executes simple numbering, however, this doesn't show numbering progress.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm using Windows 10 with PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least the following errors:

- You must not modify the GUI from another thread, in your case the run method is executed in another thread but you try to modify the value of the QProgressBar, in addition to displaying a widget which is not allowed. If you want to modify the GUI with the information provided in the execution in the secondary thread you must do it through signals since they are thread-safe
- The for loop is the blocking task so it must be executed in another thread.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QProgressBar,
)
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, Signal


class ProgressWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ProgressWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pgsb = QProgressBar()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.pgsb)


class BarThread(QThread):
    progressChanged = Signal(int)

    def run(self):
        percent = 0
        for x in range(0, 100000):
            percent = x / 100
            self.progressChanged.emit(percent)


class Tool(QWidget):
    """Main UI Definition"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Tool, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")
        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.bt = QPushButton("Numbering")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt)

        # Main Function Link Definition
        self.bt.clicked.connect(self.numbering)

        self.bar_thread = BarThread(self)
        self.progress_widget = ProgressWidget()

        self.bar_thread.progressChanged.connect(self.progress_widget.pgsb.setValue)

    # Main Function Definition
    def numbering(self):
        self.bar_thread.start()
        self.progress_widget.show()


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super(Tool, self).closeEvent(event)
        self.bar_thread.quit()
        self.bar_thread.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Tool()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```